# gson vs protocol buffer

Tags: protocol-buffers, gson

What are the pros and cons of protocol buffer (protobuf) over GSON?

In what situation protobuf is more appropriate than GSON?

I am sorry for a very generic question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Both json (via the gson library) and protobuf are portable between platorms; but

- protobuf is smaller (bandwidth) and cheaper (CPU) to read/write
- json is human readable / editable (protobuf is binary; hard to parse without library support)
- protobuf is trivial to merge fragments - just concatenate
- json is easily passed to web page clients
- the main java version of protobuf needs contract-definition (.proto) and code-generation; gson seems to allow arbitrary pojo usage (there are protobuf implementations that work on such objects, but not for java afaik)

If performance is key : protubuf

For use with a web page (JavaScript), or human readable: json (perhaps via gson)

Comment: Apache avro is one more alternative if you are looking for binary serialization. Contract definition (like .proto) is optional and comes with in-built RPC support

Comment: Apache Thrift is the head-to-head Apache counterpart of Google Protocol Buffers (http://thrift.apache.org/). See online for detailed comaprisons between the two.

Answer (score 0):

If you want efficiency and cross-platform you should send raw messages between applications containing the information that is necessary and nothing more or less.

Serialising classes via Java's own mechanisms, gson, protobufs or whatever, creates data that contains not only the information you wish to send, but also information about the logical structures/hierarchies of the data structures that has been used to represent the data inside your application.

This makes those classes and data mapping dual purpose, one to represent the data internally in the application, and two to be transmitted to another application. Those two roles can be conflicting there is an onus on the developer to remember that the classes, collections and data layout he is working with at any time will also be serialised.